# No output when skipping letters (letter z) when user type in number to skip a letter

Tags: java

I have this program that will output a letter or word according to the specified value input by a user. For example when a user types letter a, then the user will type again a number (e.g. 2), the output will be c. In my program it is working when a user type a single letter and the letter is until z. However when a use type a word that exceeds the number for letter z there will is no output. For example user types in xyz, and type 4 to be skipped, there is no output.

```
public class FinalsActivity2 {
    Scanner fc = new Scanner(System.in);
    char characters[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\TeonGo\\Desktop\\final2.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);

    public FinalsActivity2() throws IOException {
        System.out.print("Enter text:");
        String text = fc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter number:");
        int num = Integer.parseInt(fc.nextLine());

        try {
            for (int f = 0; ; f++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < 26; c++) {
                    if (text.charAt(f) == characters[c]) {
                        pw.print(characters[num + c]);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        pw.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new FinalsActivity2();
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing to fix: remove the exception-swallowing, and instead fix your for loop to just loop over each letter in the string. Next, I'd just print the output to the screen instead of to a file, and I'd also put all the code into the `main` method rather than having a bunch of fields for no reason and putting code in the constructor. All of these will make it easier to read the code and see what's wrong. I'd also suggest getting your IDE to format the code, indenting it appropriately. After all those changes, edit your question with the simpler code.

Comment: I think it is doing what it is supposed to and outputs `lipps`. Why would the output be `lippi` for `hello` ?

Comment: @jay-gorio Input: `hello`, number: `4`. Then: `h+4=l`, `e+4=i`, `l+4=p`, `o+4=s`. If `o` were parsed `i`, what would `e` be parsed as? Code is working fine.

Comment: Note that you can use loop over `(char)(i + 'a')` with `for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++ )` instead of that `characters[]` array.

Comment: @sachin yeah sorry. thats working the problem is that when user types in letter z and user type number to be skipped is 5, there will be no output. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: @JayGorio There is no output because it is throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, you are not seeing that because you are swallowing the Exception.What do you want it to do when the input is `z`? circle back to the start of the `character` array or just ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not seeing any output because you are getting a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you are trying to access `characters` array past `z`, since you are swallowing the exception you are not able to see it.

If you want to circle back to your `characters` array when you reach past `z` use the modulo result for getting the index. something like this.

```
    for (int f = 0; f < text.length(); f++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < characters.length; c++) {
            if (text.charAt(f) == characters[c]) {
                int idxToGet = (num + c) % characters.length;
                pw.print(characters[idxToGet]);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want to just ignore anything that goes past `z` then use the below

```
    for (int f = 0; f < text.length(); f++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < characters.length; c++) {
            int idxToGet = num + c;
            if (text.charAt(f) == characters[c] && idxToGet < characters.length) {
                pw.print(characters[idxToGet]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at your code and tried to correct it
(I know I probably shouldn't have as you need to learn these thing but did so in the interest of answering the question) to the specifications given in the comment on your question from Jon Skeet above:

> First thing to fix: remove the exception-swallowing, and instead fix your for loop to just loop over each letter in the string. Next, I'd just print the output to the screen instead of to a file, and I'd also put all the code into the main method rather than having a bunch of fields for no reason and putting code in the constructor. All of these will make it easier to read the code and see what's wrong. I'd also suggest getting your IDE to format the code, indenting it appropriately. After all those changes, edit your question with the simpler code.

as follows is an implementation of your code to said specification:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
private char characters[]= {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
            'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

    public static void main(String[] args){
      Test test = new Test();
      test.FinalsActivity2();
    }

    public void FinalsActivity2(){
       System.out.print("Enter text: ");
       String text = sc.nextLine();
       System.out.print("Enter number: ");
       int num = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
       for(int f = 0; f < text.length(); f++){
           for(int c = 0; c < 26; c++){
               if (text.charAt(f) == characters[c]){
                   System.out.print(characters[num + c]);
                }
            }
        }
     sc.close();
    }

}
```

This code seems to work well given your example.
The code does result in hello being converted to lipps when the user gives four(4) as the amount to change the alphabet by. However this is the correct output given the code h+4 = l, e+4 = i, l+4 = p and o+4 = s.

The output I get from the console when "hello" is the first input is:

```
Enter text: hello
Enter number: 4
lipps
```

and with just "o":

```
Enter text: o
Enter number: 4
s
```

The answer to your question seems to be that you've miss calculated what the output should be.

Comment: Yeah sorry that's my mistake I overlooked it. The problem here is that when I enter z, and enter 2 there will be no output. This is the challenge I am facing tight now. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: The problem is that 26 + any number is going to be greater than the number of letters in the alphabet. The way to get around this would be to add an if statement so that when the num + c is greater than 26 use characters[num+c-26]. Like this:                                                            `if(num+c < 26){
         System.out.print(characters[num + c]);
         }else{
          System.out.print(characters[num + c - 26]);
         }`